# Racket/Beginner Student Language Code Error

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages, htdp

I am trying to animate a word letter by letter using Beginner Student Language on Racket. However, this code gives me an error *"function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but found a part"*. I bolded the part that is giving me problems. Any suggestions?

(define theWord "blahlahblahblahblahbla")

(define (letterByLetter a)

(overlay (**(substring theWord 0 a)** 50 "red") (empty-scene 500 500)))

(animate letterByLetter)

Comment: What graphic library are you using? AFAIK `overlay` expects images as arguments, not strings. And you might want to check your parentheses, the error is caused by the double parentheses when calling `substring`.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a function to convert the string into an image of the text

Answer (score 1):

This is because [overlay](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html?q=animate#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._overlay%29%29) takes two or more images as arguments. It looks like you want the first argument to be a call to [text](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html?q=animate#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._text%29%29) so the form should be

```lisp
(text substring theWord 0 a)
```

However, note that [animate](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html?q=animate#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Funiverse..rkt%29._animate%29%29) will call `letterByLetter` 28 times a second in an infinite loop so will run out of letters and raise an exception! Perhaps you could compare `a` and `(string-length theWord)`...